# Installing phpmyadmin with MariaDB 10

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have successfully installed mariaDB (tested a connection, works fine) and phpmyadmin. However, when trying to access phpmyadmin, I get the following:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
Cannot load mysql extension. Please check your PHP configuration. - Documentation
```

I have attempted to install php-mysql as directed, but I get a dependency error which I cannot easily explain.

```
$ sudo yum -y install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.i386 0:5.1.6-23.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-23.el5 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15) for package: php-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.i386 0:5.1.6-23.el5 set to be updated
---> Package php-pdo.i386 0:5.1.6-23.el5 set to be updated
---> Package mysql.i386 0:5.0.45-7.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: mysql conflicts MySQL
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mysql-5.0.45-7.el5.i386 from el5_u3_base has depsolving problems
  --> mysql conflicts with MariaDB-server
Error: mysql conflicts with MariaDB-server
```

Why does mysql conflict with MariaDB-server? How do I resolve the conflict?

NOTE: this host previously had mysql (v4?) installed. I thought I had removed it completely with:

```
sudo yum remove mysql mysql-server
```

Comment: Try installing `php-mysqlnd` instead of `php-mysql`.

Comment: @Rocket: `No package php-mysqlnd available.`

Comment: I made some progress this afternoon. As @jdelaporte mentioned, I tried mariadb-compat which allowed me to see some other unresolved dependencies. Apparently, I am cursed to be using Oracle Linux (because I have several Oracle databases, I decided to go with OEL). Unfortunately, the Oracle public yum repo is HORRID and full of broken links; I had to download the dependent RPMs manually and apply them. After that, php-mysql could be installed. The downside is that now my php is downgraded from v5.3 to v5.1. :( I just can't win.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer may be to install MariaDB-compat package, since it also fulfills the dependency that mysql fills (for a mysql client package). Then try installing/updating phpMyAdmin (or php-mysql) package again.

Comment: Actually, someone offline mentioned that to me as well. It turns out to be a deeper issue, which I will explain in the comments of my original post. Frickin' Oracle.